# What is the point of "extends empty object" in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

What is difference between `class Document<T extends {}>{}` and `class Document<T>{}`

Can you give examples that show difference?

Comment: `{} | null | undefined` is the same type as `unknown`. `T extends {}` is basically `T` extends unknown` except for `null` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter with no explicit [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) is *unconstrained*, or has an *implicit contraint* to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) to which all types are assignable.  So in  `class Document<T>{}` or `class Document<T extends unknown>{}`, you can pass any type you want for `T`:

```
class Document<T>{ /**impl hopefully involving T**/ }
new Document<{ a: string }>(); // okay
new Document<string>(); // okay
new Document<null>(); // okay
new Document<undefined>(); // okay
new Document<string | undefined>(); // okay
```

On the other hand, `T extends {}` constrains `T` to the so-called "empty object type" `{}`, which corresponds to any object type or any [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) type that can be *treated* like an object by indexing into it.  If JavaScript [autoboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)#Autoboxing) a primitive type with a wrapper object, then that primitive type is assignable to `{}`.

The only primitives that don't get autoboxed in JavaScript are `null` and `undefined`, so the only values in TypeScript not assignable to `{}` are those assignable from [the `null` and `undefined` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined).

So `T extends {}` allows `T` to be anything that doesn't have `null` or `undefined` in its domain:

```
class Document<T extends {}>{ /**impl hopefully involving T**/ }
new Document<{ a: string }>(); // okay
new Document<string>(); // okay
new Document<null>(); // error
new Document<undefined>(); // error
new Document<string | undefined>(); // error
```

It's a fairly weak constraint, but it is a little stricter than `T extends unknown`, as you can see.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5YyDeAoJunwBsQookARAe3gFdJgAXAHgBUkIAPeiYAE1IwC+APgxIBOPOgDu5KrW5NRIAFxIo9AE4BLYAHMxQgBQBKANxIA9BaQUA1iACeE3NNk06Tddr1Gzl63aOzkiulO4KjMDUBAS+5lZsGhoUGsGhch6M1LwQAGY6EDxx-onJqXghEDJh8gyMXjr6AD5I2Tx5BUUm8dYQSSlYg+JYoJCwCMjMUhRI2BWExKQ1mcwiYmlVbrWKSCpqmo0G3SWBThXp4XUNPscJpxvVGRFRMcV39meSm8sRbR3oXT87yC52+TyuBz0SBaf3yALeAQ+WAEQA)